# Aviso de error en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, xml

Buenas noches el problema que tengo es el siguiente al momento de crear mi aplicacion en Android Studio me sale este aviso.
Hago lo que me dice en la sugerencia pero igual me manda otro mensaje de error
Agradeceria si me pudieran ayudar en esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Jcastillo como usas la librería de soporte de diseño versión 26, tienes que cambiar a minSdkVersion 14, como se comenta el a respuesta sugerida como duplicada.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente sea un bug de Android Studio.
Te recomiendo:

1.-Sube la version minima del sdk en tu gradle.

```
minSdkVersion 14
```

2.-Limpia el proyecto.

3.-Vuelve a compilar.

Comment: No es un bug, es configuración que soporta la support design library versión 26.

Comment: Puedes poner un screen shot de tu build gradle?

Comment: Amigo yo no soy el que pregunto, pero exactamente es ahí donde se cambia, es bueno tener más personas que sepan android!!!, saludos!